# How do i install GtkDialog in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, package-management, software-installation

I need help to find, download and install gtkdialog and it's underlying dependencies (GLib, Pango, GdkPixbuf, ATK and cairo library's) for Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

Any help or explanation would be great. (I am new to the concept of Installing software on Linux and using forums like this one.)

Answer (score 2):

This appears not to have an installation candidate for `Ubuntu Xenial Xerus`, see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/gtkdialog)

It can be installed from source with the following steps:

1. Install build essentials: `sudo apt install build-essential`
2. Download the source files with:

   ```
   wget https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/gtkdialog/gtkdialog-0.8.3.tar.gz
   ```
3. Unpack it:

   ```
   tar -zxvf gtkdialog-0.8.3.tar.gz
   ```
4. Enter the folder:

   ```
   cd gtkdialog-0.8.3/
   ```
5. Install it with:

   - `./configure`
   - `make`
   - `sudo make install`

Source:

https://www.tecmint.com/gtkdialog-create-graphical-interfaces-and-dialog-boxes/

https://code.google.com/archive/p/gtkdialog/downloads

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for the help. The links are dead. (found new ones no problem there.) anyway. After trying to unpack it with the tar -xvf /location/gtkdialog-0.8.3 command i get the output: gnzip: stdin: not in gunzip format. tar: child returned status 1. tar: error is not recoverable: exiting now.

Comment: What is the compression format for the file and did you download it completely

Comment: Hi, this is the source link [https://www.tecmint.com/gtkdialog-create-graphical-interfaces-and-dialog-boxes/], This is the actual packet link: [https://code.google.com/archive/p/gtkdialog/downloads]. and yes i downloaded the complete file and the format is .tar.gz (tar gunzip) how do i go at this? this is the actual package that i am using [Gtkdialog 0.8.3 source package  Type-Source  Featured  OpSys-Linux Jan 6, 2013 558.57KB].

Comment: Hi. thanks for the help. i keep you updated. I just learned from you that i need -xvzf instead of xvf only to unzip gunzip compressed files.

Comment: Hi. it all worked out just fine. the only thing i had to do was to verify what kind of compression was used on the file. with the commando "file" and change the unpacking command to my needs. I turned it into tar -xvfz gtkdialog-0.8.3 -C /newdirectorylocationwhereiwantedittobe/there. Thanks alot for the effort ^^.

Comment: Yes sorry I missed the `z` in there so sorry